# How to use Image Picker for Collection View Cells

Tags: ios, swift, view, collections, cells

I am currently making an application that requires the user to use image picker to load images to `CollectionViewCell`. I am using one prototype cell that has the UIImageView, however whenever I post a photo it only goes to the first cell and not to the individual cells I have pressed. I was wondering how I could make the code in a way that targets the specific cell I have tapped and use the image picker accordingly.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
    cell.tag = self.integer[indexPath.item]

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

    cell.myAdd.addTarget(self, action: "importPicture:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)


    return cell
}

func importPicture(sender: UIButton) {
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let
    cell = myCollection.cellForItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)) as! MyCollectionViewCell
    var newImage: UIImage

    imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    let pickedImage1 = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
        currentPickerTarget.image = pickedImage1
        currentPickerTarget = cell.myImages


    myCollection.reloadData()

}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate protocol

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    print("\(indexPath.row)")
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    // 1
    // Return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleLongGesture:")
    self.myCollection.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
}
```

Comment: When do you update currentPickerTarget ? General idea: save the selected indexPath in a variable in didSelectItemAtIndexPath and after picking up the image reload the item with proper image.

Answer (score 0):

this happens because you are rewriting the image picked and adding it to the index 0 of the array, i would remove the line `cell.myAdd.addTarget(self, action: "importPicture:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)` and just modify the function `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
}` to save the indexpath.row of the cell you chose early, then execute the function importPicture and when the user finish picking his picture you save it into your images array with the index that you previously saved, with that if you choose the same cell the image will just rewrite herself and new cells will add new images to the array.